# how to get all rows from .sortable() method pass it to another function

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using JQuery DataTable 1.10.12. I have one dataTable which is using `.sortable()` method for dragging rows inside table. `.sortable()` works properly, but problem is that how can I get all sorted rows with data, as I need it on button click. Here is what I have tried already. please suggest me, what should I do?

```
 $('#datatables-playlist-tracks tbody').sortable({
 helper: 'clone',
            update: function (event, ui) {
                console.log('update: ' + ui.item.index())
                var result = $(this).sortable('toArray', {attribute: 'id'});
                console.log(result);

            },
            start: function (event, ui) {
                console.log('start: ' + ui.item.index())
            }
        });

        $('#datatables-playlist-tracks tbody').disableSelection();
```

Need to pass rawData to this function.

```
function getSortedRows(rawData){
console.log(rawData);
}
```

Comment: This is already built into sortable, see: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize or if you need an array: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray

Comment: Unless you are looking to get that detail from DataTable; it too should have this function. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve